# How do I perform rm -v !(*.yaml) in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

In the script it reads:

```
rm -v !\(*.yaml\) ;\
```

this produces

```
rm: cannot remove '!(*.yaml)': No such file or directory
```

but works fine in the command line.
Have tried escaping in various ways:

```
'\!\(\*.yaml\)'
`\!\(\*.yaml\)`
`!\(*.yaml\"\)`
"\!\(\*.yaml\)"
```

Can't seem to figure out the appropriate escape sequence, I simply don't understand. Escaping the brackets was my first step. Then trying to escape the `!`, then the `*`. Also tried no escaping, using back-ticks but I got the error "rm missing operand". Im a little stumped. Have been at it for about an hour - just "rm everything not yaml"... Can anyone perhaps spot the error/suggest a fix?

I have also tried #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash. Thought it would maybe have some effect.

Comment: Presumably your Linux distro's dotfiles run `shopt -s extglob` by default in interactive shells -- without a distro changing the defaults, it's normally off for interactive shells too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`!(x)` is a Korn shell glob operator. `bash` supports a subset of `ksh`'s globs operators including that one but only after `shopt -s extglob`¹

So:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -f -- !(*.yaml)
```

Will remove all the non-hidden files in the current directory except those whose name ends in `.yaml`.

In any case, glob operators are *not* recognised as such when quoted, so using `\` (one of the quoting operators in Bourne-like shells) won't help.

The equivalent in the `zsh` shell would be:

```
rm -f -- ^*.yaml
```

For which you need `set -o extendedglob`.

(it does also support `!(x)` after `emulate ksh` or `set -o kshglob`).

There is no equivalent in the `sh` language, though you may find that some `sh` implementations, like those based on `ksh` support `!(x)` as an extension.

---

<sup>¹ as that affects the shell syntax parsing, the `shopt` command must have been executed *before* a line containing one of those ksh extended operators is *read* and parsed. For instance in `bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; echo !(x)'`, you get a syntax error because the whole line is parsed first (with extglob not on yet), and then `shopt` is run (well, would have been run if not for the syntax error). `bash -O extglob -c 'echo !(x)'` is fine.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Bash has a feature where the variable `GLOBIGNORE` can tell the shell what filenames to remove from a glob, leaving the rest to be operated on (in this case with `rm -v`).

Here's a demonstration:

```
mkdir /tmp/this-test
cd /tmp/this-test
touch one.yaml two.yaml three.json four.txt
echo *
```

Produces:

```
four.txt one.yaml three.json two.yaml
```

Now set `GLOBIGNORE` to ignore the .yaml files, and then disable its effect:

```
GLOBIGNORE='*.yaml'
echo *
GLOBIGNORE=
echo *
```

Produces:

```
four.txt three.json
four.txt one.yaml three.json two.yaml
```

The command `rm -v *` instead of `echo *` would remove the files in the directory whose names don't end in `.yaml`.

`GLOBIGNORE` can have a list of glob expressions, each separated by a colon (`:`).  For example if I had set  `GLOBIGNORE='*.yaml:*.json'`  in the above demonstration, that `GLOBIGNORE` value would have removed the .yaml and .json filenames from the glob list, so only the `four.txt` file would have been displayed or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach combining find & rm ...

starting with a folder containing five files

```
cd /path/to/files/
touch one.yaml two.yaml three.txt four.yaml five.json
```

you can use the utility find, that allows the exclusion of names patterns, however to scan non-recursively with find you'll need to set -mindepth and -maxdepth to 1.

```
find /path/to/files -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.yaml' -exec rm -v '{}' \;
removed '/path/to/files/three.txt'
removed '/path/to/files/five.json'
```

then you can use rm -v individually on every file found. This might be slow on huge numbers of files as it separately invokes rm on every file.

However you can also use -delete to get the same effect, without the verbose output, but will be faster.

```
find /path/to/files -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.yaml' -delete
```

Comment: You can end that last command with `-print -delete` to see the files as they're deleted.  `-print` alone is just the default if no action was given, which is why `-delete` alone doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Izkata - thank you, I always forget you can combine -print and -delete (+1)